# Get data from firebase like android java by Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firebase to List, I mean get all custom object from database to my list. I know in Android java it is

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ");
  docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
   public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    City city = documentSnapshot.toObject(City.class);
   }
 });
```

How can I do this with Flutter ?

Comment: similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042915/how-to-transform-the-data-received-from-cloud-firestore-into-a-map/59043376#59043376)

Comment: I saw your link and folowing but I still don't get data, a list just an empty list

Answer (score 2):

In flutter, [cloud firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) package/plugin is developed for working

Just, setup the plugin and read the documentation for fetching and uploading data from step by step.